# Find max in array using threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore, barrier

How would you do this in c with a binary reduction and a barrier implemented using binary semaphores?  This is the code I have so far.  It doesnt have a barrier, and I'm confused on how to make one.  Would I need mutex locks for this?

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <pthread.h>
# define arrSize 10

struct StructMax
{
    int iMax;
};

int arr[arrSize];

void *thread_search_max(void *);

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;
    struct StructMax *st_main,*st_th;
    int FinalMax;

    st_main=(struct StructMax*)malloc(sizeof(struct StructMax));

    int iCount;
    for(iCount=0;iCount<arrSize;iCount++)
    {
        printf("Enter Value of arr[%d] :",iCount);
        scanf("%d",&arr[iCount]);
    }        
    pthread_create(&tid,NULL,thread_search_max,NULL);

    st_main->iMax=arr[0];

    for(iCount=1;iCount<arrSize/2;iCount++)
    {
        if(arr[iCount] > st_main->iMax)
        {
            st_main->iMax=arr[iCount];
        }
    }    

    pthread_join(tid,(void**)&st_th);    

    if(st_main->iMax >= st_th->iMax)
    {
        FinalMax=st_main->iMax;
    }    
    else
    {
        FinalMax=st_th->iMax;
    }


    printf("Final Max : %d \n",FinalMax);
    return 0;
}


void *thread_search_max(void *para)
{
    struct StructMax *st;
    st=(struct StructMax*)malloc(sizeof(struct StructMax));

    int iCount;
    st->iMax=arr[arrSize/2];


    for(iCount=arrSize/2 + 1;iCount<arrSize;iCount++)
    {
        if(arr[iCount] > st->iMax)
        {
            st->iMax=arr[iCount];
        }
    }    

    pthread_exit((void*)st);        
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Write your allocations like: `st_main = malloc(sizeof *st_main);`. Much shorter, no pointless casts, and a bit safer too.

Comment: As almost everyone else, you cast `malloc()`, [which is not needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) but ignore it's return value, which is bad practice. Also, use a mutex, and don't use a global variable, pass the array to the thread function via the last argument to `pthread_create`. And remember each `malloc()` should be matched by a `free()` somewhere.

Comment: Semaphore? Barriers? I'd avoid them searching for maximum in array, they'll hurt performance enough to push you back to a straight non parallel execution. If you're doing this for performance I'd consider to use _atomics_ (with a very careful implementation) or even (if your architecture allows you this _trick_) using _volatile_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You didn't include `stdlib.h`**: which is the main problem, but you should also consider some other minor fixes that would make your code robust.

The problem with not includeing `stdlib.h` is that the compiler assumes that `malloc()` returns an `int`, so you can see that this will cause problems.

If you enable compiler warnings, you can prevent this kind of things, I sometimes forget some headers, but I don't get too far because the compiler reminds me.

Assuming that you work with `gcc` then

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -o output $sourceFiles -pthread
```

will prevent compilation in this case.

This is an improved version of your program, with the `stdlib.h` header included

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define arrSize 10

struct StructMax
{
    int iMax;
};

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *thread_search_max(void *);

int main()
{
    pthread_t         tid;
    struct StructMax *st_main;
    struct StructMax *st_th;
    int               FinalMax;
    int               arr[arrSize];

    st_main = malloc(sizeof(struct StructMax));
    if (st_main == NULL)
        return -1;
    int iCount;
    for (iCount = 0 ; iCount < arrSize ; iCount++)
    {
        printf("Enter Value of arr[%d] :",iCount);
        scanf("%d",&arr[iCount]);
    }
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_search_max, arr);

    /* lock the mutex, in this secction we access 'arr' */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    st_main->iMax = arr[0];
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    for (iCount = 1 ; iCount < arrSize / 2 ; iCount++)
    {
        /* lock the mutex, in this secction we access 'arr' */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (arr[iCount] > st_main->iMax)
        {
            st_main->iMax = arr[iCount];
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    pthread_join(tid, (void **)&st_th);

    if (st_main->iMax >= st_th->iMax)
    {
        FinalMax = st_main->iMax;
    }
    else
    {
        FinalMax = st_th->iMax;
    }
    printf("Final Max : %d \n", FinalMax);
    free(st_th);
    free(st_main);
    return 0;
}

void *thread_search_max(void *para)
{
    struct StructMax *st;
    int               iCount;
    int              *arr;

    arr = para;
    if (arr == NULL)
        return NULL;
    st = malloc(sizeof(struct StructMax));
    if (st == NULL)
        return NULL;
    /* lock the mutex, in this secction we access 'arr' */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    st->iMax = arr[arrSize/2];
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    for (iCount = arrSize /  2 + 1 ; iCount < arrSize ; iCount++)
    {
        /* lock the mutex, in this secction we access 'arr' */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (arr[iCount] > st->iMax)
        {
            st->iMax = arr[iCount];
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit((void *)st);
}
```

see the usage of the `mutex`, it prevents the two threads from accessing the value simultaneously. And how global variables are not needed, besides they are a really bad idea when multithreading.

Comment: how would you do this if you had to start off with a bunch of threads containing two numbers each, and they had to build up the solution from there?  Let's assume the array size is a power of 2, for the sake of my sanity, and yours.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above optimization, the pthread should be created with attrributes specifying that is joinable (to guarantee that pthread_join() will block untill the thread specified is done). You can do this by declaring a 'attr' of type pthread_attr_t.
The sample coded looks like below.

```
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
pthread_t tid;

pthread_create(&tid, &attr, function, args);
//....
pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

pthread_join(&tid, (void **)status);
```

The pthread_attr_destroy() is called before pthread_join(), because attr is no longer required once pthread_create() is invoked with appropriate arguments.